# Как сдвинуть текст в кнопке?

Tags: java, android

На скриншоте клякса - это background кнопки. В этой кнопке text. Применил к нему gravity"centre", но он получается не посередине. Как его подвинуть немного? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: xml покажи, где это всё есть

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_circle_right"
        android:onClick="varieties"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:text="Сорта"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:fontFamily="@font/my_font"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="290dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_right" />

Comment: Это кнопка та что на скрине

Comment: Здесь сама картинка со сдвигом. Надо просто слева добавить прозрачную область в картинку, чтобы текст был по центру.

Comment: Ааааа ну кстати может быть)))

Comment: Спасибо. Посмотрю

Comment: Ну а вообще есть какая то возможность двигать текст по кнопке из угла в угл?